# String.format causes an error

Tags: scala

Scala code I have

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s %6d", "someName", someLong))
```

and the error:

```
 overloaded method value format with alternatives:
[error]   (java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,<repeated...>[java.lang.Object])java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (java.lang.String,<repeated...>[java.lang.Object])java.lang.String
[error]  cannot be applied to (java.lang.String, Long, String)
[error]       System.out.println(String.format("%s %6d",  "someName", someLong))
```

How do  I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To illustrate Randall's answer.

If you're over fifty, use Randall's answer, but if you're under forty or can still wear fitted shirts, use the f-interpolator!  Life is short.

```
scala> String.format("%s %6d", "someName", someLong: java.lang.Long)
res8: String = someName      5

scala> val someName = "Bob"
someName: String = Bob

scala> f"${someName} ${someLong}%6d"
res10: String = Bob      5
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason what you're trying doesn't work is that the Java code cannot handle Scala's `AnyVal` types.

Instead, use Scala's counterpart:

```
println("%s %6d".format("someName" someLong))
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
printf("%s %6d%n", someName, someLong)
```

Comment: the first example seems incorrect, but I even can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, that was very clumsy of me. It is fixed, now.